# What's difference with data-element and data-object?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

In the phase of learning datastructure. I'm just know the data-element is the subset of data-object. But not totally understand the major difference between "data-element" and "data-object". Why classify these two concepts？？

Comment: Suggest you post pure conceptual computer science question in https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, in object oriented programming, a data object (often) has one or more data elements. A data element can itself also be a data object, but it does not have to be. If it is also a data object, then that data object can again have some data elements of its own, and so you get a hierarchy.

But a data element can also be an *atomic* value, also called *primitive* value. This is not a data object, but a plain value. This value cannot have data elements or other members. Examples of data elements that are not data objects: numbers, booleans (false/true).

The term "data elements" is used when speaking of data objects. It highlights the relationship, not so much the type of that element. They are often implemented as attributes, properties, where they can be accessed with a key (a name).

#### Concluding:

A data object can have data elements, although we can imagine "empty" objects.

A data element belongs to a data object, but it does have to be a data object itself.